# Redirect stdout / stderr to bash script

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

Apologize if this is a really simple question, but I couldn't find anything on google for "redirect stdout and stderr to bash script" and "redirect bash script output to another bash script".

I know this will redirect stdout and stderr to `log.txt`, but I'm not sure how to redirect it to a bash script.

```
java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar > log.txt 2>&1
```

Ideally something that behaves like above and is like so

```
java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar > "./script.sh" 2>&1 # script.sh uses the $1 argument for input
```

Comment: `java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar ## don't ##> "./script.sh" 2>&1` hope you didn't do this which overwrites your script

Comment: The script is just an `echo`, and I have VCS, but thanks for the fair warning

Comment: Show the output you are expecting from the `jar`, stdout and stderr. what are you expecting to happen when there are both?

Comment: It's a java program, so stderr would be a stacktrace from some error. https://pastebin.com/raw/pizCj5PF Here's what I get when running the first command I put in my example

Comment: As the command line has a limit, and you are expecting to pass stack traces that could be long, I would abandon the idea of using command line and read from stdin in your script

Comment: Yes, but not even the shortest messages are coming through with the solutions I got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xargs to move data from a pipe into an argument:

```
java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar 2>&1 | xargs ./script.sh
```

to pass everything as a single argument:

```
java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar 2>&1 | xargs --null ./script.sh
```

Comment: @Mika: note that besides `xargs`, the important point in this answer is the use of a pipe `|` to communicate between the two processes.

Comment: Would this print all the output as 1 argument? Since that's what I'm after

Comment: @Mika if you use `xargs --null ./script.sh` it should pass a single argument.

Comment: I just tried `java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar 2>&1 | xargs --null ./notify.sh` with notify.sh being

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "\"$1\""
```, no output

Comment: Interestingly enough, your second solution works fine with `cat log.txt`. This is the output I get from the first command in my original question: https://pastebin.com/raw/pizCj5PF

Meaning the redirect works fine for files, and yours works fine for cat but not stdout which doesn't terminate?

Comment: You can try `stdbuf -o0 java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar 2>&1 | xargs --null ./script.sh` however if the java doesn't terminate how can you expect to put all of the output into an argument?

Comment: Well I don't expect it to terminate, I want to continuously run the script for all new output

Comment: you just cannot have all the output in a single argument and expect it to be continuous.

Comment: I'll mark this as the solution, as it works fine for terminating programs

Answer (score 0):

You can use command substitution for that:

```
 ./script.sh $(java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar 2>&1)
```

In addition to perreal's answer, if your script could be changed to read from stdin instead of expecting a parameter, you could also use a pipe:

```
java -jar build/libs/bot-kt-1.1.3.jar  2>&1 | ./script.sh
```

Comment: If `script.sh` is just `echo "\"$1\""`, then neither of these echo anything back, even though the jar is run just fine

Comment: Do you get your prompt back?

Comment: What's the point of the script if just echoes its input? Is it a placeholder script?

Comment: Okay, if your Java program produces continuous output that you want to process with your script, then please reconsider my *second* solution, ie., read the input from stdin inside the script. A simple test script looks like this `while read line; do echo "script processed ${line}"; done`. If you just pipe the output of the Java program into this script you should see output even while the Java program is still running. The only difference from the point of view of the script is the actual processing will move to the body of the `while`-loop and your input will be inside `${line}`, not in `$1`.